# How do I stop Xcode static analyser from reporting object leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

This is my method on my class XXObject

```
+ (XXObject*)objectWithValuesFromFromXml:(struct _TBXMLElement *)element
{
    XXObject *object = [[XXObject alloc] init];
    ...
    return object;
}
```

XCode says `Potential leak of an object stored in 'object'`.

The details says "3. Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'object' is returned from a method whose name ('objectWithValuesFromXml:') does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy, 'alloc' or 'new'. This violated the naming conventions..."

But the documentation () says "The names of factory methods have the following initial form:

```
+ (id)typeRemainderOfMethodName
```

where type is the class name minus the prefix and RemainderOfMethodName often begins with With or From."

What can I do?

Comment: Call the method `xXObjectWithValuesFromFromXml`?  What does "minus the prefix" actually mean?

Comment: Are you using ARC or MRC?

Comment: I'm not using ARC. What is MRC?

Comment: Manual reference counting. Sometimes called MRR (manual retain and release), too.

Comment: I thought that autorelease will release my object when the current method exits. What am I missing?

Comment: For historical reasons I'm using MRC.

Comment: No, autorelease will release the object when the autorelease pool is drained (i.e. you yield back to the run loop). But whomever called this method could safely retain this object and use it for its own purposes.

Comment: @trojanfoe "minus the prefix" means that you remove the two first letters of the class name. Objective-C does not have name spaces, so the convention is to use a two-letter prefix for each group of classes instead. My example has a class called XXObject. XX is the "name space".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a +1 object. Only methods that start with `copy`, `mutableCopy`, `alloc` and `new` should return +1 objects. This static analyzer warning is correct.

The documentation you reference is also correct, that factory methods often follow that naming convention. But they do not return +1 objects. They return `autorelease` objects. Autorelease objects are those objects that will be released when the autorelease pool is drained (typically when you yield back to the app run loop). But by returning autorelease object, the caller has an opportunity to `retain` the object and use it for its own purposes.

By the way, you can suppress this warning by explicitly specifying `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` in your method declaration, which is used to inform the compiler that your method does not conform to naming conventions. This is inadvisable, though. This `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` should only be used in those cases where you have an existing method that does not conform to established naming conventions, but you cannot change it for some reason (e.g. an API that is already being used and changing the memory semantics would break existing code).

I would suggest that you either:

- Rename this routine:

  ```
  + (XXObject*)newObjectWithValuesFromFromXml:(struct _TBXMLElement *)element
  {
      XXObject *object = [[XXObject alloc] init];
      ...
      return object;
  }
  ```
- Return `autorelease` object:

  ```
  + (XXObject*)objectWithValuesFromFromXml:(struct _TBXMLElement *)element
  {
      XXObject *object = [[[XXObject alloc] init] autorelease];
      ...
      return object;
  }
  ```

---

As an aside, you would generally not refer to your class in this method declaration, for example, you might use `instancetype` in the method declaration, and reference `self` when you call `alloc`:

```
+ (instancetype)objectWithValuesFromFromXml:(struct _TBXMLElement *)element
{
    XXObject *object = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
    ...
    return object;
}
```

This ensures that if this class is ever subclassed that this method will continue to work for the subclass, too.